# Calculating a Cost Using a Stored Procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, syntax

I have two tables in my database: Package and Shipment. There can be multiple packages in a shipment. (Hence each package has a unique shipment_track_no)

```
Package(package_number, type, content, weight, shipment_track_no)

Shipment(tracking_number, sender_id, receiver_name, receiver_phone_number, method, is_delivered, shipment_date)
```

I would like to create a stored procedure in MYSQL that would calculate the cost of a shipment, iterating through the packages in a shipment.

Calculation has several steps to it:

- First, the package is valued according to its type (1-5 enum).
- Then extras are added if the package has special content (1-3 enum).
- After calculating the cost of each package of shipment I add it to a
  common sum. According to the delivery method of the shipment an extra
  sum might be added as well.

The code that I came up with using all available resources that I could find is below. I think I am messing up the syntax but the main flow should be all-right. I would really appreciate if anyone helps me with the correct syntax.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS cost_of_shipment;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE cost_of_shipment(IN shipment_id_fed int(11),
                                    OUT total decimal(12,2))  
BEGIN 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temporaryTable;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporaryTable engine=memory SELECT package_number, Package.`type`, content, weight FROM Package WHERE shipment_track_no = shipment_id_fed;

DECLARE i INT(11) DEFAULT 1;

DECLARE rowCount INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
SET rowCount = (SELECT COUNT(package_number) FROM temporaryTable); 



DECLARE shipment_cost DECIMAL (12,2) DEFAULT = 0.00;


WHILE (i <= rowCount)
BEGIN

        DECLARE ipackage_number INT(11), ipackage_type INT(11), icontent INT(11), iweight DECIMAL(12,2), package_cost DECIMAL(12,2);

        SELECT ipackage_number = package_number, ipackage_type = package_type, icontent = content , iweight = weight FROM temporaryTable LIMIT 1;
        IF ipackage_type = 1 OR ipackage_type = 2 OR  ipackage_type = 3
        THEN
        SET package_cost = 10;
        END IF;

        IF ipackage_type = 4
        THEN
        SET package_cost = 15;
        END IF;

        IF ipackage_type = 5 AND iweight<20
        THEN
        SET package_cost = 20;
        END IF;

        IF ipackage_type = 5 AND iweight>20
        THEN
        SET package_cost = 20 + (iweight-20)*1;
        END IF;

        IF icontent = 2
        THEN
        SET package_cost = package_cost + 10;
        END IF;

        IF icontent = 3
        THEN
        SET package_cost = package_cost * 1.1;
        END IF;

        shipment_cost = shipment_cost + package_cost; 

        DELETE FROM temporaryTable WHERE package_number = ipackage_number;
        SET i = i  + 1
END

        IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE tracking_number = shipment_id_fed) = 2
        THEN
        SET shipment_cost = shipment_cost +10; 
        END IF;

        IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE tracking_number = shipment_id_fed) = 3
        THEN
        SET shipment_cost = shipment_cost +25; 
        END IF;

    SELECT shipment_cost INTO total FROM Shipment;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL, why are you using constructs, such as `TOP` that are specific to SQL Server?

Comment: I am a beginner in SQL and I used both SQL Server and MySQL, that's why I am really confused. For the TOP construct: SELECT ipackage_number = package_number, ipackage_type = package_type, icontent = content , iweight = weight FROM temporaryTable LIMIT 1; should do I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redesigned the tables for Package and Shipment; added cost attributes to them. I dealt with the issue with creating triggers for inserting and updating a Package.

**On Insert Trigger for calculating the cost of a Package**

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER package_cost_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Package
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF new.type = 1 OR new.type = 2 OR new.type = 3  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 10.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 4  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 15.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 5 AND new.weight< 20.00 THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 20.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 5 AND new.weight> 20.00  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 20.00 + ROUND((new.weight -20.00),0);
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 1 THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 0.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 2  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 10.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 3  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost *1.1;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

**On Update Trigger for calculating the cost of a Package**

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER package_cost_update BEFORE UPDATE ON Package
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET new.cost = 0;
        IF new.type = 1 OR new.type = 2 OR new.type = 3  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 10.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 4  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 15.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 5 AND new.weight< 20.00 THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 20.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 5 AND new.weight> 20  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 20.00 + ROUND((new.weight -20.00),0);
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 1 THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 0.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 2  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost + 10.00;
        END IF;

        IF new.content = 3  THEN
             SET new.cost = new.cost *1.1;
        END IF;
    END;
    $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

**On Insert Trigger for calculating the cost of a Shipment**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER shipment_cost_insert AFTER INSERT ON Package
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM Package WHERE Package.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`);
        IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 1 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 0.00;
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 2 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 10.00;
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 3 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 25.00;
    END IF;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**On Update Trigger for calculating the cost of a Shipment**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER shipment_cost_update AFTER UPDATE ON Package
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM Package WHERE Package.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`);

    IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 1 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 0.00;
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 2 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 10.00;
    END IF;

    IF (SELECT method FROM Shipment WHERE new.`shipment_track_no` = Shipment.`tracking_number`) = 3 THEN
        UPDATE Shipment SET Shipment.`shipment_cost` = Shipment.`shipment_cost` + 25.00;
    END IF;

END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```